# How to add categories to a custom post type using wp_insert_post($new_post);

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, forms

I have a custom post type 'memberfile', and a function for users (members) to upload files. Uploaded files are automatically posted as a 'memberfile' post in the backend.

In the form for uploading the file, users can choose tags and categories. And I would like to have this tags and categories uploaded with the memberfile post.

The tags work fine, but the categories are not taken into account, they don't show up in the memberfile post.

**This is the PHP part that makes the post from the upload:**

```
if (!empty($_FILES['file_upload'])) {
    $file_title = sanitize_text_field($_POST['file_title']);
    $file_upload = $_FILES['file_upload'];
    $file_type = isset($_POST['file_type']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['file_type']) : '';
    $file_category = isset($_POST['file_category']) ? sanitize_text_field($_POST['file_category']) : '';

    $uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload($file_upload, array('test_form' => false));

    if (isset($uploaded_file['file'])) {
        $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $uploaded_file['file']);

        // Check if attachment was created successfully
        if (!is_wp_error($attach_id)) {
            $attach_path = get_attached_file($attach_id);
            $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_path);
        } else {
            echo $attach_id->get_error_message();
        }
    }

    if (isset($uploaded_file['file'])) {
        $attachment = array(
            'post_mime_type' => $uploaded_file['type'],
            'post_title'     => sanitize_text_field($_POST['file_title']),
            'post_content'   => '',
            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
            'guid'           => $uploaded_file['url']
        );

        $attach_path = get_attached_file($attach_id);

        $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attach_id, $attach_path);

        // Create new post for uploaded file
        $new_post = array(
            'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($_POST['file_title']),
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'memberfile', // custom post type for uploaded files
            'tax_input' => array(
                'post_tag' => array($file_type),
                'category' => array($file_category), // set the first selected category
            ),
            'meta_input' => array(
                'file_path' => $uploaded_file['file'],
            ),
        );

        if (isset($attach_id)) {
            // Add attachment as metadata to the new post
            update_post_meta($new_post['ID'], '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id);
        }

        wp_set_post_terms($new_post_id, array($file_type), 'post_tag');
        wp_set_post_terms($new_post_id, array($file_category), 'category');


        wp_insert_post($new_post);

        echo 'File uploaded successfully.';
    } else {
        echo $uploaded_file['error'];
    }
}
```

**This is the form to upload a file, which is transformed into a memberfile post**

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label style="display:block;" for="file_title">Title:</label>
        <input type="text" name="file_title" id="file_title" required>

        <label style="display:block;" for="file_category">Category:</label>
        <select name="file_category[]" id="file_category">
        <option value="">Select Category</option>
        <?php
            $terms = get_terms(array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'hide_empty' => false,
            ));

            $excluded_terms = array('Business Strategy', 'Energy Management', 'GET TO KNOW', 'Interview', 'Personal Branding', 'Selfcare', 'Uncategorized');

            // Sort the terms array by name
            usort($terms, function ($a, $b) {
                return strcasecmp($a->name, $b->name);
            });

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                if (!in_array($term->name, $excluded_terms)) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                } else if ($term->count == 0) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $term->name . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>

        <div id="file_upload_container">
            <label id="file_upload_label" for="file_upload">
                <i class="fas fa-cloud-upload-alt"></i>
                <span>Click to add or drop files</span>
                <span id="selected_file"></span>
            </label>
            <input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" onchange="handleSelectedFile()" required>
        </div>
        <label style="display:block;" for="file_type">Type:</label>
        <div id="type_buttons">
            <?php
            $type_options = array('Image', 'Excel', 'PDF', 'Word');
            foreach ($type_options as $option) {
                echo '<button type="button" value="' . strtolower($option) . '">' . $option . '</button>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" name="file_type" id="selected_type">
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </form>
```

**This is how I create the custom post memberfile**

```
function register_cpt_memberfile()
{
    register_post_type('memberfile', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x('MemberFiles', 'memberfile'),
            'singular_name' => _x('MemberFile', 'memberfile'),
            'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'memberfile'),
            'add_new_item' => _x('Add New MemberFile', 'memberfile'),
            'edit_item' => _x('Edit MemberFile', 'memberfile'),
            'new_item' => _x('New MemberFile', 'memberfile'),
            'view_item' => _x('View MemberFile', 'memberfile'),
            'search_items' => _x('Search MemberFiles', 'memberfile'),
            'not_found' => _x('No MemberFiles found', 'memberfile'),
            'not_found_in_trash' => _x('No MemberFiles found in Trash', 'memberfile'),
            'parent_item_colon' => _x('Parent MemberFile:', 'memberfile'),
            'menu_name' => _x('MemberFiles', 'memberfile')
        ),
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'description' => '',
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'page-attributes', 'post-formats'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_icon' => '',
        'menu_position' => '5',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'rewrite' => false,
        'show_in_rest' => true,
    ));
```

Any idea on how I can make sure that when someone selects a categorie in the form when uploading a file, that is will show at the custom post in the backend as categorie?